# New flag label looks weird and coarse

Tags: discussion, flags, design

### Examples:

> [image]

- Wrong spacing within the `spam` label.
- The word "spam" is very unclear due to extremely small size and thin font.

---

> [image]

- The weird combination of color makes the `active` label utterly unreadable. It's anti-aesthetic!

### Browsers:

- **Firefox** (35.0)
- **IE** (11.09600.17501)

All produce the same effects.

Comment: Mod-only text with similar styling is also affected. It's making my job just a teeny weeny bit harder.

Comment: I took a look at the CSS, and all I can say is... eugh. The spam flag indicator is, for some weird reason, using the `bounty-indicator-tab` class (meant, obviously, for bounty amounts), and then overriding it with a bunch of additional CSS hacks. (`bounty-fix`, really?) Also, there's whitespace both inside and outside the marker span, which gives fun and possibly browser-dependent results when it's collapsed.